# Controller For One To Many Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, one-to-many, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.2.

I have 3 tables (writters, publishers and categories) all of the is **One to Many Relationships** with table named **books**.

I'm not really sure what the problem is, but everytime i call the the column from 2 of them (nama_penerbit from publishers table and nama_kategori from categories table)from my view blade, it throws me an error ***Trying to get property of non-object***

Here is my models

#### Book.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'judul',
        'label',
        'isbn',
        'tanggal_terbit',
        'status',
        'id_penulis',
        'id_penerbit',
        'id_kategori',
    ];


    // Book with Writter
    public function writter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Writter', 'id_penulis');
    }

    // Book with Publisher
    public function publisher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Writter', 'id_penerbit');
    }

    // Book with Category
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Writter', 'id_kategori');
    }

}
```

#### Publisher.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Publisher extends Model
{



    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_penerbit',
    ];

    // Relation Book with Publisher
    public function book() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'id_penerbit');
    }
}
```

#### Writter.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Writter extends Model
{



    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_penulis',
    ];


    // Relation Book with Writter
    public function book() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'id_penulis');
    }
}
```

#### Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_kategori',
    ];

    // Relation Book with Category
    public function book() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'id_kategori');
    }
}
```

#### my-view.blade.php

```
<span>{{ $book->writter->nama_penulis }}</span> // works like a charm
<span>{{ $book->publisher->nama_penerbit }}</span> // throw me an error
<span>{{ $book->category->nama_kategori }}</span> // throw me an error
```

My question is why ***nama_penerbit and nama_kategori*** throw a error while the other one works well

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `Writter` model for all three relationships, so fix these relationships by setting correct models:

```
// Book with Publisher
public function publisher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Publisher', 'id_penerbit');
}

// Book with Category
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id_kategori');
}
```